# Express save file on disk from post request (gzip)

Tags: xml, file, express, http, request

I try to save file after post request, the response should be an xml file but it return weird data.

> ��m~�'z��O4B��M]�3�οT��]G�s���rLM2��9�*��v�`W/�y����V����Z���`4...

I can download it from the browser with the dialog box but i can't achieve to save it as a file with my backend.

```
        const dataString = '0=0&1=1&2=2&3=3&4=4&5=5&6=6&7=7';
        request({
            method: 'POST',
            uri: 'http://localhost:3000/template/d-thx-file/1498716378',
            headers: {
                'Connection': 'keep-alive',
                'Pragma': 'no-cache',
                'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
                'Origin': 'http://localhost:3000',
                'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36',
                'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
                'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
                'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
                'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
                'Referer': 'http://localhost:3000/Produit.html',
                'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
                'Accept-Language': 'fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
            },
            resolveWithFullResponse: true, // optional, otherwise replace `res.body` with just `res` below
            gzip: true,
            encoding: null,
            body: dataString
        }).on('response', function (res, req, body) {
            res.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./' + res.headers.date + '.' + res.headers['content-type'].split('/')[1], { encoding: 'utf8' }));
        });
```

I try lot of request options : gzip: true, encoding: null, ... but nothing work

Comment: HTML only returns readable character.  See Wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references.  GZIP also returns readable characters.  So what you did worked.  So two things 1) You do not have xml 2) The characters being returned are a different encoding than the one you are using.

Comment: Your data looks similar to another posting where the decryption wasn't working properly.  You may need to specify https instead of http.  See posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59845202/encrypt-and-decrypt-string-given-key